# paginação no vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, paginação

Estou observando o parâmetro da url para fazer uma paginação no vue.js3

No meu onMounted eu pego o parâmetro e busco a pagina referente  do parâmetro no beck end (se for 1 vou buscar a primeira pagina 2 a segunda a assim vai), o beck end vai me retorna 5 registros o numero total de registros numero total de paginas e numero da pagina atual.

Eu pego isso e monto a tela

```js
   const {
      params: { page },
    } = useRoute();
    const getpage = () => {
      return page ? page : store.state.page;
    };
   onMounted(async () => {
      const onGetTributo = async page => {
        if (!page) page = 1;
        try {
          var resp = await servico.getGridPage(page);

          return [resp.itens, resp];
        } catch (err) {
          console.error("Erro ao buscar Tributo!", err);
        }
      }; 
      
      itensPaginacao = await onGetTributo(page);
     

    });
```

Retorno do back end

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

ai pra fazer a navegação eu tenho uma função que faz

```js
 router.push("/tributo/" + page)
```

O comportamento que eu espera que ele tivesse era navegar para a nova url com o novo parametro e que ele montasse o componente de novo mas ele so navega e eu tenho que dar um f5 para mostrar o conteúdo novo

Para funcionar por enquanto eu fiz:

```js
 const newContentTable = (page) => {
      router.push("/tributo/" + page)
      setInterval(function(){ document.location.reload(true); }, 10);
      console.log("/tributo/" + page)
    };
```

Minha duvida é qual a forma certa de recarregar esse componente quando eu navego para a próxima pagina

Answer (score 0):

> O comportamento que eu espera que ele tivesse era navegar para a nova url com o novo parâmetro e que ele montasse o componente de novo, mas ele só navega e eu tenho que dar um <kbd>F5</kbd> para mostrar o conteúdo novo.

Você precisa fazer o Vue forçar a re-renderização do componente para que ele seja recarregado. Existem duas formas de fazer isso, quando você utiliza VueRoute.

A primeira forma é utilizando `key`.

```
<router-view :key="$route.path" />
```

Quando você usa o `key` e ele é modificado, o Vue escreve o componente novamente.

A segunda é usando um `watch` para verificar mudanças no `$route`.

```
methods: {

    created() {
        this.carregarDados();
    },
    carregarDados() {
         api.get(`dados/${this.$route.params.id}`);
    },
},
watch: {
   $route() {
       this.carregarDados();
   }
}
```

Uma terceira opção é usar os [Navigations Guard](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#in-component-guards):

```js
beforeRouteUpdate (to, from, next) {
  // just use `this`
  api.get(`dados/${to.params.id}`);
  next();
}
```